# Why isn't the error message showing in .err-msg?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Trying to output 'message' from a JSON array into "div.err-msg".

I am passing the error message (response.message) in the JSON array into "div.err-msg". However, the whole JSON array appears in the console log with no issues but doesn't output the 'message' into the div.

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('.auth-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);
    submitForm($form);
  });
});


function submitForm($form){

  $(".err-msg").html('<img src="public/images/ajax-loader.gif">');

  $.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    method: $form.attr('method'), 
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function(response){
      response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

      if(response.success){

        if(!response.signout){
          setTimeout(function(){
            $(".err-msg").html(response.message);
            window.location = response.url;
          },5000);
        }

        $(".err-msg").html(response.message);
      } else if(response.error) {
        $(".err-msg").html(response.message);
      }
      console.log(response)
    }
  });
}
```

PHP (One of the error messages):

```
if($status === 'missing_fields'){
    echo json_encode([
        'error'   => 'error', 
        'message' => '<p class="error">All fields mandatory!</p>',
    ]);
}
```

I'm expecting 'All fields mandatory!' to be inside div.err-msg

If I don't enter any fields and then submit form. Console log shows `{error: "error", message: "<p class="error">All fields mandatory!</p>"}`. It appears to bee working fine but it just won't `.html()` the `'message'`.

Comment: You will get error in the `.error()` call back - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Comment: What is the response from the backend? What exactly is logged?

Comment: can you edit your answer to show what `console.log(response)` returns?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to the options of your `$.ajax` call:

`dataType: 'json',`

and comment this line:

`response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);`

**UPDATE**

As you haven't posted all of the code, I can't debug it for you. So instead I've mocked-up a demo of what you seemingly want to do. See the following code (tested, working). I've made a few small optimizations to point you in the right way of thinking.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST))
{
        if (empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password']))
                $response = ['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'All fields mandatory!'];
        else
        {
                // Validation stuff here.
                $response = ['status' => 'success', 'message' => 'OK!'];
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
label
{
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.message
{
        padding: 1em;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 1em;
        border-color: currentColor;
        border: 1px solid;
}
.error
{
        color: red;
}
.success
{
        color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<label>Username<br><input type="text" name="username"></label>
<label>Password<br><input type="password" name="password"></label>
<button type="submit">Login</button>
<div class="message"></div>
</form>
<script>
$('form').submit(
        function (event)
        {
                var $this = $(this);
                var $message = $('.message');

                event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax(
                        {
                                url: $this.attr('action'),
                                method: $this.attr('method'),
                                data: $this.serialize(),
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (response)
                                {
                                        if (response.status == 'success')
                                        {
                                                // Do your success stuff.
                                                $message.addClass('success');
                                        }
                                        if (response.status == 'error')
                                        {
                                                // Do your error stuff.
                                                $message.addClass('error');
                                        }

                                        $message.html(response.message).show();

                                        console.log(response);
                                }
                        }
                );
        }
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did that and now returns `Object: 'error'   => 'error', 'message' => '<p class="error">All fields mandatory!</p>'`